# Open new separate R session from R script for several processes

Tags: r

Does anyone know if its possible to source R scripts from within a main R script but have each sourced file run in a separate R session? I am trying to run multiple R processes in parallel (without using complicated parallel libraries) and thought calling a new process for each split step I have could speed things up (I have lots of RAM).

Comment: Parallelisation is probably easier than what you're trying to do at the moment, particularly if you're on an OS that supports multicore (i.e. not Windows). In that scenario, you can either use `mclapply` which is almost identical in use to `lapply`, or use `registerDoMC` and either the `foreach` `%dopar` construct or `plyr` with its `.parallel` parameter. On Windows you can use either `foreach` or `plyr` with `registerDoSNOW`. The main difficulty with SNOW is remembering to export packages and objects to each cluster.

Comment: There is also the package `snowfall` which offers a very easy to use interface to `snow`. Snowfall does actually exactly what you asked for: it starts several R processes and distributes the work among them. I haven't used it on Windows, though. But since Windows obviously can run several independent processes at a time, I would be surprised if it didn't work.

Comment: you can use `system("Rscript file.R", wait = FALSE)`